# Слетает кодировка Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

При запуске некоторых приложений появляются непонятные символы, появилось после того как поставил русский язык, когда вернул обратно на английский всё хорошо, как можно исправить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:
Пуск (ПКМ) -- параметры -- время и язык -- формат даты, времени и региона -- язык -- административные языковые параметры -- изменить язык системы -- поставить галку на Бета версии использовании юникода UTF-8